# Ajax post to ASP .NET 2.2 Razor page gives 404 error

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't seem to get this to work with the latest .NET Core 2.2 Razor.
I hard-coded the URL just to make sure it is correct. The ajax script is inside a partial view, but I did test to move the script into the main page with the same 404 result.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://localhost:44349/Admin/Catalog/Products/Edit?handler=Filter&id=1',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
});
```

And here is my handler:

```
public IActionResult OnPostFilter(int id)
        {
            return new JsonResult("test");
        }
```

I disabled AntiForgery Token in Startup just to make sure that wasn't causing my problem:

```
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o =>
    {
        o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    });
```

Comment: What `Admin/Catalog/Products/Edit` stand for? Share us your full razor page and project structor.

Comment: It is a page at: Areas > Admin > Pages > Catalog > Products > Edit.cshtml ...  I can go to a page /Admin/Catalog/Products/Edit/8 and it the GET works, but when I try to AJAX POST with a handler, I can't get it to work. I have another project that is an earlier version of .NET Core Razor and it works. I believe there is something in 2.2 that changed that is causing my problem.

Answer (score 3):

`404` means the url is incorrect.

Razor Pages need to set a `RequestVerificationToken` header when sending a `POST` request:

Add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` on your view, then change your ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://localhost:44349/Admin/Catalog/Products/Edit?handler=Filter',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
                 id: 1                  
            },
            headers:
            {
                "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. The code I posted didn't have the AntiForgeryToken because I disabled it in Startup. I have tried adding the token in the header and I still get a 400 error. It was also recommended to change the header name to "XSRF-TOKEN" but that doesn't work either.

Comment: you can also disable it by
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken(Order = 1000)]
https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification